# Generating a html table with php using 2 json objects and sorting by date

Tags: php, jquery

I have a JSON object with data (date, kms and duration) that I have used to make an HTML table. The data is stored in order via date so its displayed how i want.  See below.

```
Date        Km's    Duration    Part/Service
15/10/19    16.05   01:30:09    
14/10/19    16.8    01:30:42    
03/10/19    13.47   02:30:36    
02/10/19    15.79   01:18:54    
30/09/19    17.5    01:26:56    
29/09/19    13.15   01:49:38    
26/09/19    12.1    01:36:37
```

I have another JSON object with an array of parts (4th column) and a date. I can't work out how to cycle through both to add the part row in the table in its correct row (before date of first table).

I have tried to run another for each loop within the first table for each loop to check if there is a date before the first table date, and if so insert the row and remove the element from the array so it can't duplicate. I also had to change both dates to strtotime(); otherwise the comparison of dates would only check the first number (days)

```php
            foreach($jsonData1 as $elementKey => $element) {

                    $durMinutes = gmdate("H:i:s", $element->elapsed_time);
                    $new_date_format = date('d/m/y', strtotime($element->start_date_local));
                    $kms = round($element->distance / 1000, 2);

                    foreach($jsonData2 as $eKey => $e) {

                        $date_ =  $e->date_;
                        $date2_ = strtotime($date_) ;
$date2 = str_replace('20', '', $date2);                 


                        if($date2_ < $dateToCompare){


                            echo "<tr id='".$rowId."'>";
                            echo "<td></td>";

                            echo "<td></td>";
                            echo "<td></td>";
                            echo "<td>".$date2_."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            /
                            unset($jsonData2[$eKey]);

                                }

                    }




                    echo "<tr id='".$rowId."'>";
                    echo "<td>".$new_date_format."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$kms."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$durMinutes."</td>";
                    echo "<td></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                    $rowId++;



            }
```

Json objest added, there was a lot of data so I shortened it. also some rangon inputs i placed in while testing

```
jsonData1 

{"0":{"resource_state":2,"athlete":{"id":17300746,"resource_state":1},"name":"Morning Ride","distance":16046.3,"moving_time":4898,"elapsed_time":5409,"total_elevation_gain":0,"type":"Ride","workout_type":null,"id":2789696693,"external_id":"5017296437_1571097318.gpx","upload_id":2956200741,"start_date":"2019-10-14T23:58:35Z","start_date_local":"2019-10-15T09:58:35Z","timezone":"(GMT+10:00) Australia\/Brisbane","utc_offset":36000,"start_latlng":[-27.39,152.94],"end_latlng":[-27.39,152.94],"location_city":null,"location_state":null,"location_country":"Australia","start_latitude":-27.39,"start_longitude":152.94,"achievement_count":12,"kudos_count":1,"comment_count":0,"athlete_count":1,"photo_count":0,"map":{"id":"a2789696693","summary_polyline":"dddfDqgnd\\qBb@GTI|Dd@p@`@|APfAF`B[r@Ab@O^kAxBa@b@E\\H`BPx@z@rArBfCdAv@j@lA~@bDZVdAlB`A\\VTBXKt@K|Ho@lBaDvBsCnCeEnHE^Yb@qB~AaC|@wA`AMnAeBxCGt@\\lAdBvClBfB~BrAQF?zBFpES`@sB`Aq@~BCjCIV[b@}AfAcATyAx@oAxAwFq@eAfAK~Ha@vCGrAIdDJnBCpBq@`EG|ALXANo@fBO~@ExB|@rAt@h@t@VzADl@p@gBdBgAd@sBe@mBZCtBN\\r@d@xBdC|CbCnANvAFbE_@c@UqBQp@StF]vA_AdAEb@qAv@}@v@]BFa@l@Eb@_@p@HCzBiBPcADeBHWTGx@\\l@z@@Jm@QWVh@\\v@rAdAh@d@E`AYZDS\\@XfAp@rAnC\\@d@oDpAw@x@}@XmD`Aq@|CQt@c@fCw@jBNrAgCW}BYg@f@KGKLMQK@MdAGB_@a@Ut@y@p@mAN@V^KbABj@Mx@s@v@_@~@XjA?ZMl@mA~Ba@VgAJmAOiBn@cAx@m@HmAQo@XG`@BvBaB`BgAt@AtDS|@UHqBiAq@uAeAg@mCBqEq@aAEgCvAgDr@uFPMMoCPm@Cw@Y]FyC_CwB}Bu@_@Yo@?eBFGpBUzAf@lAa@nBqA?_@M]]Qw@@iAYq@i@w@}AO{ABoAD[|@cBO_@RB\\OxBsBP]t@_@Va@xBg@\\BLc@jB?rAa@Xf@[`@`@LDTTC@mDcAUbBa@Ze@`@wAnAa@VBXXLEEe@W[TKz@`AJXITDL\\S@_A}AeBSKOFP_@xAl@hBf@VNNZH?@Yq@sAJApBnADIK[cAcAuAg@WiAUYNQj@`Aj@QTD`@f@|Aj@RX`AZX`@|@aAx@l@NAr@mApBkAv@_AvAa@nCo@RD\\M`@s@@[d@Mp@g@La@f@o@BIU?cAVr@{AlBc@f@m@Ru@]kDImC~@wOe@][q@k@uGk@eDs@PII?m@Qc@oA_AuDaEmAyDUuA@i@H]|@w@B{@mAyBgAu@ZqAFiABmCEyBIMXy@Ck@We@sAa@uAeC_@aAg@My@sBm@c@mBsB{@qAaA{BSsBzBsD@i@\\gAIiCk@oBq@cAPwDPYvBe@","resource_state":2},"trainer":false,"commute":false,"manual":false,"private":false,"visibility":"everyone","flagged":false,"gear_id":"b6289997","from_accepted_tag":false,"upload_id_str":"2956200741","average_speed":3.276,"max_speed":13.6,"device_watts":false,"has_heartrate":true,"average_heartrate":138.7,"max_heartrate":171,"heartrate_opt_out":false,"display_hide_heartrate_option":true,"elev_high":86,"elev_low":86,"pr_count":1,"total_photo_count":0,"has_kudoed":false},"1":{"resource_state":2,"athlete":{"id":17300746,"resource_state":1},"name":"Morning Ride","distance":16804.8,"moving_time":5069,"elapsed_time":5442,"total_elevation_gain":0,"type":"Ride","workout_type":null,"id":2787313119,"external_id":"5017296437_1571012018.gpx","upload_id":2953665443,"start_date":"2019-10-14T00:17:15Z","start_date_local":"2019-10-14T10:17:15Z","timezone":"(GMT+10:00) Australia\/Brisbane","utc_offset":36000,"start_latlng":[-27.39,152.95],"end_latlng":[-27.39,152.94],"location_city":null,"location_state":null,"location_country":"Australia","start_latitude":-27.39,"start_longitude":152.95,"achievement_count":7,"kudos_count":1,"comment_count":0,"athlete_count":1,"photo_count":0,"map":{"id":"a2787313119","summary_polyline":"nncfDymod\\{@KwBkBoAe@aGMmAiAsB`@{A?e@sA{A{AsGoDwA[MTKE_BqBmF{DoAqBy@[]w@My@mAcBRyL_@cDmAmEa@y@m@UKs@QsOKOEJAj@YYFcAIqBFc@c@Xa@`ANz@Ov@[j@JpA_ASYaAW@Bx@WBu@qAq@Ec@{B}@qBOm@sAOWwAa@c@_Bg@}@w@oAwBk@e@Qu@cAeAi@\\e@r@Q`Ac@MJzBZTAJg@CZn@Qp@jApCtHhDhAjDvBlErAnAXj@tB`A|@nA`Al@bFZxBtEv@nGAtBQPG`DoANSTKh@i@j@qA`@K?^WIIqBWqARkFsB`@Co@m@NAG_@o@_@Yc@wAa@eA}AQeB\\eCSGo@uAO`Au@tAP^LpAxAzDb@\\b@fAd@A^vAz@RgAXDHd@HH\\`El@hDEzDVT?d@a@zB_A~@fAl@tA|@v@lBjC@|AgAvDUtB_@JcA]SF~AdBHlAo@\\Su@w@`B@n@]CM{@i@x@q@VcALyBr@FbCg@aAw@a@uAf@g@z@hACXP@b@c@C?`@_@`@C^}A~@cA~AVlAZx@hAdBpCxFz@nApAt@Ax@aDnBYbA^?p@s@n@A|@q@`Du@lA`@dA]vANfAS|@`@IvAfARh@f@Ol@wA|A@\\LQh@VFIW_@JAh@XRG?S]SD]XTn@Fd@f@Al@dAt@l@|B_@v@i@RsGj@GVFj@Xc@b@v@xALTUzB_@l@m@R}@RMz@BM{@sAmBsGaM[U}@UgLn@oDp@_@NO\\Kc@^kBEy@gAuBi@g@cAgC{@wAkAC?NEJkAh@SGYb@Uc@uBeAoBKN\\a@P{@e@]cAHQRVVBC_@wD{B{@@[qAqBcBH]EmA\\qAG]w@u@HEdA\\h@p@NSKc@HGf@f@NQQq@i@_@FMt@Ep@f@|BgC|@L`@ZbAfB|AzEfAn@z@RlClERCdAaBdAi@f@aAFe@d@GC_@[OiAFj@iAj@]f@Fz@r@Pt@Jy@Mq@JWfBu@lAO^]NDl@aAFj@j@NEk@|@iBX~@`AUAc@f@eAn@_I~@c@xAj@n@G~AfBxBZxBz@vDfCnAxBXTpDm@ZVRf@f@LbHX~B~Ah@t@h@A","resource_state":2},"trainer":false,"commute":false,"manual":false,"private":false,"visibility":"everyone","flagged":false,"gear_id":"b6289997","from_accepted_tag":false,"upload_id_str":"2953665443","average_speed":3.315,"max_speed":11.8,"device_watts":false,"has_heartrate":true,"average_heartrate":140.5,"max_heartrate":167,"heartrate_opt_out":false,"display_hide_heartrate_option":true,"elev_high":79,"elev_low":79,"pr_count":3,"total_photo_count":0,"has_kudoed":false},"2":{"resource_state":2,"athlete":{"id":17300746,"resource_state":1},"name":"Evening Ride","distance":13474.6,"moving_time":4104,"elapsed_time":9036,"total_elevation_gain":0,"type":"Ride","workout_type":null,"id":2761382734,"external_id":"5017296437_1570090432.gpx","upload_id":2926459145,"start_date":"2019-10-03T08:16:33Z","start_date_local":"2019-10-03T18:16:33Z","timezone":"(GMT+10:00) Australia\/Brisbane","utc_offset":36000,"start_latlng":[-27.34,152.98],"end_latlng":[-27.36,152.97],"location_city":null,"location_state":null,"location_country":"Australia","start_latitude":-27.34,"start_longitude":152.98,"achievement_count":5,"kudos_count":4,"comment_count":0,"athlete_count":3,"photo_count":0,"map":{"id":"a2761382734","summary_polyline":"zkzeD{xud\\Kb@GHOFoD\\aANk@GQII?c@cAGKOEYBe@PsCf@y@OKBKFIJCLCp@SdAA`@EHK@cF_@oRmBoPyAs@Bu@M_VcCwJw@ILIn@M|B]zD]zFW`Dc@Le@?gRiBSQEK?MJc@GGIARIDICINHKEIDBFI@GHDKCGHCKCGBHGFPGF@JGHHE?]BIH?@JGBFCK@?JP@GCEI@MGDEKAHINFGGEDGE[PDCH@HFIL@BHEFQBWCk@L^HPI\\AG@DDG?QFBIMAHBNOGDBJRNSKDUAKAJGECHPNH?DJt@d@VOQMq@MEMIEQ?EFFEBHIACIIEO@DFH@FI@JDGF?AMDGI?LXYWMFPCJ@DFm@MEJR@PJGBJOBFAJl@DOIISGAFGCKN{@j@sIt@BxFp@tJ|@RSFOFc@H{Ad@c@DU?K?JM\\Cn@ETBK?K@JEHCI@KDG?JDGCHFIGF@HJKPFI?CIIBIPBHHGBGAMGHGTBHAM?YEn@EDHUDe@?HGTFMBUGFALDKEHBH@IFGOR@s@HUNcAVMV@jCXDDAL]GNL?NMlBAFQGCIFa@FiAK?GJKbBJjALFPSLuBKo@@NAP]fCNNJU@g@I?GHGZBLFDHIDa@CMI?EHCXHLHOFaAYTBZAXBHLED[BqA?II?EH@LCXCRIVFPJ?FO?[@WYNCLCVFLHDFCDSGQD]AQGEKf@FKFe@AMG@EHI|@JEBKH_AG[MYHLLBAKFEBNEb@KZERA^GNKE@i@Ho@A[ICAJGz@@f@FV?LBNJHPSDQNiC?KESFHGn@GEAIBJGRQzAEILEBq@Da@NYBQBHCm@DIvARhADzCTlFn@dIv@PBFLF@JCrB?jFl@pKbA~NfApFh@DIDe@Jm@B_@?YBQVWPAt@H^ClBa@~@UL?JFZt@LNRJ`@?h@GtA_@jIeBbA`@zCbBLHN`@E`@Ur@S^iAfBoB|E~@fAj@dBj@pA\\Nn@Mb@?RHRRFRHv@XlAFv@JDf@IZO`@[bBMVRTd@D^DjADXTPpAb@nAh@HJHL?PyAtCOZ@r@L|@DJ\\Ph@J|@@hAMf@OL[JMd@}@hByAZG\\[JEjA?HEDMBc@BGJGV_@HCn@o@TC~@DtAZPNr@Rr@G`AYrAGfA?X?fAv@RAFGLo@JuAF_BD]GAZcCXoFs@A_BOgC[CSHi@F_AJk@JA\\Bn@RvX~BlHt@rAHPBxA\\hHv@nDh@Z\\nAdAxDrEjIjJXb@QKCK","resource_state":2},"trainer":false,"commute":false,"manual":false,"private":false,"visibility":"everyone","flagged":false,"gear_id":"b6289997","from_accepted_tag":false,"upload_id_str":"2926459145","average_speed":3.283,"max_speed":22.9,"device_watts":false,"has_heartrate":true,"average_heartrate":112.7,"max_heartrate":159,"heartrate_opt_out":false,"display_hide_heartrate_option":true,"elev_high":97,"elev_low":97,"pr_count":3,"total_photo_count":0,"has_kudoed":false},"3":{"resource_state":2,"athlete":{"id":17300746,"resource_state":1},"name":"Morning Ride","distance":15789.8,"moving_time":4281,"elapsed_time":4734,"total_elevation_gain":0,"type":"Ride","workout_type":null,"id":2756177555,"external_id":"5017296437_1569974724.gpx","upload_id":2921078316,"start_date":"2019-10-02T00:06:32Z","start_date_local":"2019-10-02T10:06:32Z","timezone":"(GMT+10:00) Australia\/Brisbane","utc_offset":36000,"start_latlng":[-27.39,152.94],"end_latlng":[-27.39,152.94],"location_city":null,"location_state":null,"location_country":"Australia","start_latitude":-27.39,"start_longitude":152.94,"achievement_count":14,"kudos_count":3,"comment_count":0,"athlete_count":1,"photo_count":0,"map":{"id":"a2756177555","summary_polyline":"~qcfDorod\\SLMr@c@v@c@ZmAUmBoB]M_AQiBBiCOE]H_FGUC_B\\iB?q@GvAa@jBOvCgAlAIZa@R}@DiAa@_BmBs@oAcDkBNQL?f@Xx@RfDrDvA~@RGD_Ah@Wl@IBKm@WeBOy@iAO{@_@Hg@Qe@]QW_@uAyA}@cAyAeByAuAY{@]o@cAa@CWMk@yA[Yw@uASkCLy@GoAF]j@mA@u@Vu@PUPHx@Sh@CXUdAa@tCxA|@|@l@Tj@_@NUXQR]ZQpADlA]NJDqAJOBl@FA?c@HFFVJHDEHs@?{@ZgAKOuAGqAn@_Ft@yDgBEIBYKQ{@PQw@aAaC][i@wA@SJMb@ITTHI?OSQs@MQiAWq@yBsCc@KOJWjAA\\GDc@{@Cs@Dk@lAeCLk@OY}@CQg@IaAoAeAM[Ky@EgBRwBZMnDkC`@{AZeEbAq@f@Jr@h@hAhB~@LfBUfANrA\\HL`F~BZj@LbA\\Rf@DbBjBzBzCAh@Gh@u@nCL`GIpAGb@IL_AB}@i@y@w@kBUYa@Iu@S@i@_@u@MQ@a@PM_@qAg@g@mAsAa@eA{@{A{@qACGg@Yo@m@UKS@Ul@GOSy@I[RWh@MAI[JaAV[VGUG[N_@`@K@MkDNSdBCcC@_BjASp@QdB?xAJ|AEt@Sh@c@VaAAq@JeAi@Si@Kh@N|AIrAiAnCLp@ARc@~@CNBp@JXUC]UO_@E[KESNHb@CVMAu@mAQM_@@OG{@aDIo@]_@Mi@mAQKKI{@_@g@}Ag@sAiA_AiBi@c@Y_Aa@W]k@]V_@l@S^C^WDQMDr@AbA`@Z?Ha@GGDZr@Ur@pArCtHjD`AtCzB`FnAbAd@v@vB~@r@jARRt@`@ZDxDLtBzD`AtEL`AWRSbH]Vk@AKFKLKp@g@l@_B`@EIZKuBc@yANiFwBRD?K]_@REBKIW]Qm@s@sA_@iAwASiB\\_CYO[mAGGKBQdAk@dATh@JjAV\\Pt@v@jB^Xf@bAb@CJLFRC`@LXx@L?JQHu@Nn@NL^rDd@`ADzAIrEXhAQnAg@Hi@BIJ?v@z@XdA`@r@x@f@jAhB|@z@tDdC\\l@lAdAdBRxA\\zDzB`At@Jl@^x@RR`BGvAc@f@x@d@RxBBfDT`C|Al@x@l@D","resource_state":2},"trainer":false,"commute":false,"manual":false,"private":false,"visibility":"everyone","flagged":false,"gear_id":"b6289997","from_accepted_tag":false,"upload_id_str":"2921078316","average_speed":3.688,"max_speed":11.3,"device_watts":false,"has_heartrate":true,"average_heartrate":135.4,"max_heartrate":170,"heartrate_opt_out":false,"display_hide_heartrate_option":true,"elev_high":103,"elev_low":103,"pr_count":4,"total_photo_count":0,"has_kudoed":false}}
```

```
jsonData2 (rows to add to the original table during construction)  

[
  {
    "component":"fork",
    "date_":"21\/10\/2019",
    "servicetype":"gfhfh",
    "notes":"fhgfghfgh"
  },
  {
    "component":"fork",
    "date_":"02\/10\/2019",
    "servicetype":"gfhfh",
    "notes":"fhgfghfgh"
  },
  {
    "component":"fork",
    "date_":"03\/06\/2019",
    "servicetype":"gfhfh",
    "notes":"fhgfghfgh"
  },
  {
    "component":"fork",
    "date_":"18\/02\/2019",
    "servicetype":"gfhfh",
    "notes":"fhgfghfgh"
  },
  {
    "component":"fork",
    "brand":"ppiopoip",
    "date_":"16\/10\/2019"
  },
  {
    "component":"fork",
    "brand":"ppiopoip",
    "date_":"16\/10\/2019"
  }
]
```

I'm hoping there is an easier optin to do this as I think my attempt is way off?

** 
I have found an error and updated the code to reflect, the second and first date formats were incorrect. I have changed $date2 to the correct format by replacing 20 from 2019 to  19.

It works beter but only compares the first numbers "dd" and doesn't take the month and year into consideration.

Comment: hi, can you show us the json content?

Comment: Updated with json

Comment: show please JSON of `jsonData1`

Comment: Updated, there is alot of random data in jsonData1, but I only want the following values (date, kms and duration) .

Comment: @AnthonyHill How related `jsonData1` and `jsonData2`? By index (`count(jd1) == count(jd2)`) ? There is some kind of grouping (`jd1['relation'] = jd2`) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but would be happy to hear any other options.

I have used substr() to break down the dates and compare the year first, month and then days. I will just post the if statements below that I used, posted in place of the original if statement. The rest of the code is identical.

```
if(substr($date2,6,2) >= substr($date1,6,2)){

                            if(substr($date2,3,2) >= substr($date1,3,2)){

                                if(substr($date2,0,2) >= substr($date1,0,2)){
```